# How to get migration of Database in c# project

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have two Source projects. Both are using the same database. If I will do the migration in one project(let us say adding a new table or new column or etc.), it will reflect in the database. And it will create one .cs file in that project. But how can I get that migration in another project which is using the same database?

Comment: how about putting, accessing, migrating the database in a specific library project that's used by both projects?

Comment: Make use of the generated .cs file in the second project as well( I mean replace the old file for project 2 with the newly generated file in project 1)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1) Move the database code into it's own project so it can be referenced and re-used in other projects via a project or dll (lib) reference.

And then either:

1) Place both projects into the same Solution, create a Context project for the Data layer so when you make changes to the data context classes, the changes propagate to both projects.

2) Add the database project as a reference, reference the DLL from both.

**** Basically separate your data layer and re-use it where needed and don't replicate or copy the code into multiple projects, that's how you end up with unnecessary code duplication and more work for you in the future. It also makes it easier if you're using code migrations, to perform them from a single point.